# Are Win32 Scrollbars allowed to be updated from worker threads?

Tags: winapi, concurrency

Long story short, after spending a lot of time tracking down a crash it turns out that 'SetScrollInfo' is not threadsafe - calling it from multiple background threads at once can corrupt memory leading to a crash.

Looking at the documentation I do not see any requirements about calling the function from the thread owning the window, or serializing calls to the function.

Is this expected behavior and do we need to make sure to only run similar functions from the main thread / via locking in the future, or is this a bug in windows (10)?

Oh and if anybody wants to verify, adding the following to a new win32 project will lead to the crash after executing it a handful of times:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

HANDLE hWaitEvent = ::CreateEvent( nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr );

DWORD WINAPI SetScrollPosThread( __in void *dummy )
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject(hWaitEvent, 100);

    SCROLLINFO info = {sizeof(info)};
    info.nMin   =   0;
    info.nMax   =   reinterpret_cast<int>( dummy );
    info.nPage  =   1024;
    info.fMask  =   SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE;

    for (size_t i=0;i<16;++i)
    {
        ::SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_HORZ, &info, FALSE);
        ++info.nPage;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void StartThreads(LONG windowWidth)
{
    ::ResetEvent( hWaitEvent );
    for (size_t i=0;i<32;++i)
    {
        LONG newWidth = windowWidth * (i + 1) / 33;
        DWORD threadID;
        ::CloseHandle( ::CreateThread(nullptr, 0, SetScrollPosThread, reinterpret_cast<VOID*>(newWidth), 0, &threadID ) );
    }
    ::SetEvent( hWaitEvent );
}

[...]

            case IDM_ABOUT:
                RECT rc;
                ::GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc );
                StartThreads( rc.right - rc.left );
                break;
```

Edit: The callstack of the crash (Win10 x64). Also happens on multiple colleague's machines. No virus scanner or third party DLLS appear to be loaded in the modules list.

```
    ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@12()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpReportHeapFailure@4()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpHpHeapHandleError@12()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpFreeHeapInternal@20()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
    comctl32.dll!CUxScrollBar::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)   Unknown
    comctl32.dll!CCSetScrollInfo()  Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!_ThemeSetScrollInfoProc@16()    Unknown
    user32.dll!SetScrollInfo()  Unknown
>   TestScrollBarCrash.exe!SetScrollPosThread(void * dummy) Line 141    C++
```

Comment: In general, Win32 GUI isn't thread-safe. You should use the API only from the same thread that runs the message loop (aka GUI thread). To communicate from another thread with the GUI thread, a safe way is to post messages (using `PostMessage()`) to the GUI thread. The message will be processed within the GUI thread, so it is safe to access the GUI from the message handler.

Comment: That is exactly how I implemented my fix.

Comment: Please provide more information about the crash. Does the UI thread crash or one of the background threads? Where is it executing when it crashes? What's the exception type? I've added your code to the stock Windows project in Visual Studio, but I cannot get it to crash.  I've run Debug and Release x86 builds more than a dozen times each, and each run I triggered the Help>About 10 to 20 times.  After many tries, _sometimes_ the widow style changes causing it to be redrawn with a fat resize border and old-style title bar.  No crashes though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash with the provided code, and the question doesn't provide details (like a call stack, exception code, etc.) for the crashes the author has observed, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm not back in the office until tomorrow - I can append those then. It crashes somewhere in the windows internal callstack of SetScrollPos in the worker threads in vector code (I think it was a theme function?)

I reproduced it in win10 x32 and x64

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace; I've retracted my close vote.  Here's a story of a concurrency bug in the vicinity of _ThemeSetScrollInfoProc.  It's not a solution or even a smoking gun, since that bug was in the application, but it's tantalizing.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071228-00/?p=24003

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the stack trace.  I doubt the bug is in the heap code--that just where the problem was detected.  Further up is the common controls and theme libraries.  Are you and your colleagues by chance using a custom UI theme?  If not, then perhaps you've found a concurrency bug in the theme code.  Few applications stress that path as hard as your demo code, so it's plausible such a bug could exist undetected for a while.  You could try reporting it to Microsoft.

---

WinAPI functions that operate on windows (i.e., take an HWND as a parameter) should be thread safe.  For performance and separation of concerns, however, they generally should be called only by the same thread that owns the window.

PostMessage and InvalidateRect/Wnd, are reasonable ways for code running in other threads to signal a window in the UI thread that it needs to update. This approach reduces coupling and makes it easier to reason about the re-entrancy issues.

Many of the windowing functions are implemented by sending one or more messages to the target window.

(If you look up the SBM_SETSCROLLINFO message, you'll see a note that applications should call SetScrollInfo instead of sending the message directly. That's a hint that SetScrollInfo may be implemented in terms of this message.)

Unlike posted messages, sent messages don't go through the message queue.  When sent from the thread that owns the window, they are directly dispatched to the window procedure.

When sent from a different thread, however, SendMessage strives to create the illusion that it's directly dispatched.  This illusion requires additional overhead, so sending many cross-thread messages can be a performance bottleneck.  But it should not cause a crash.

(Cross thread use of SendMessage has some limitations.  For example, sending to a thread in another process may require marshaling of the message parameters, which SendMessage can do only for system messages.)

Sending a message to another thread can cause [possibly surprising re-entrancy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)* in the sender's window procedure, but that's not the problem here since your background threads don't have window procedures or even a thread message queue.

SetScrollInfo, and other WinAPI functions that operate on windows, should be thread safe, but the synchronization required to send messages between threads may be substantial when it's done frequently.

I cannot reproduce the crash you're seeing, so I cannot say definitively that SetScrollInfo doesn't have a bug in this regard, but my guess is there's something else going on.

---

* Thanks for link @IInspectable.

Comment: > Unlike posted messages, sent messages don't go through the message queue; they are directly dispatched to the window procedure. In effect, sending a message is making a function call.


That isn't true. SendMessage marshals the call to the window's owning thread when used from a background thread. This is stated in MSDN:


> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure.

Comment: GetWindowText also does not peek into data structures - it uses SendMessage under the hood and those messages get marshaled into the owning thread.

Comment: @H. Arlinghaus:  GetWindowText is special when is crosses process boundaries.  I've corrected that and added a citation.

Comment: @H. Arlinghaus:  The "system switches to another thread" part is kinda sloppy writing. Reading on, it says:  "Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code." In other words, when the receiver calls something like GetMessage or PeekMessage. If there's just one message pump in the receiving thread, the sent message will be serialized relative to the posted messages, but good luck if there's a modal dialog running! I'll update my answer.

Comment: GetWindowText cheating makes sense cross process. I still disagree on cross thread sendmessaging being an issue - you state that the sent messages are processed by the sending thread causing potential issues with thread local storage, and that they will be processed by the non owning thread. That simply isn't the case, the messages get queued to the owning thread. This can cause issues with reentrancy, but not with TLS or simultaneous execution. Why SetScrollInfo directly messed with the window structures instead of sending a message and letting the default handler deal with it is a mystery.

Comment: Say that window procedure not thread safe, have no sense. Because it always called from the thread, which create window.

Comment: *"Most WinAPI functions that operate on windows \[...\] are not thread safe"* - That's not how we commonly use the term *"tread safe"*. Those APIs are perfectly *"thread safe"* in the traditional sense, in that they will not corrupt memory due to data races when called from concurrent threads. As for the correction you're working on see [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983).

Comment: As for the rest of this proposed answer, that's pretty hilariously uninformed opinion presented as if it were factually correct. Obvious down-vote material. The only reason I won't is because I retired from doing any sort of quality control under the [current policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/1889329).

Comment: I suggest to add reference links to back the claims about thread-safety up. Also, formatting functions, data types and constants as code would make the post easier to read.

Comment: @zett42:  Which claims specifically?  After the latest edit, I'm not making any claims, but an argument about thread safety.  I disagree with your formatting suggesting.  When function names, data types, and constants are simply nouns in prose, I generally avoid code formatting unless it's necessary for disambiguation or getting the parser to understand what I wrote.  SO's formatting of inline code is pretty heavy-handed and visually distracting.

Comment: The first sentence. I don't see how you are backing that very generic claim up. The rest of the post is mostly about `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` which I can agree with, but not all of the Win APIs that operate on `HWND` are implemented (solely) in terms of them. Even for `SetScrollInfo` this is just a guess. We don't know for sure if it does other, not thread-safe things behind the scenes, besides sending `SBM_SETSCROLLINFO`.